# django saved queryset values returns empty on update

Tags: django, django-queryset

why does django filtered queryset returning empty queryset even after saving the queryset values to variable? [check the #outputs]
I need to get the user emails but as updated returns boolean, I have to get that before applying the update. But I am not getting the expected output.

```
    def approve_gpa_over_two(self, request):
        application_statuses = ApplicationStatus.objects.filter(application__gpa__gte=2.0,status='application_submitted')
        application_email = application_statuses.annotate(email=F('application__email')).values_list('email',flat=True)
        print(application_email)
> #output: ['abc@gg.com']
        application_statuses = application_statuses.update(status='approved')
        send_approval_email(application_email) 
        print(application_email)
> #output: []

        self.message_user(request, 'Approved all applications with GPA over 2.0')
        return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

Comment: Can you share the `send_approval_email` function?

Comment: it contains print(application_email) for now

Comment: Try converting `application_email` to a list `application_email = list(application_email)` to force the query to be evaluated when you want?

Comment: worked. but why did it replace my variable? as you can see I have defined two variables for both the operations.

Comment: Just printing a queryset does not necessarily cause it to be evaluated, you need to force it to be evaluated and cached otherwise your variable is just an unevaluated queryset that is executed fresh every time you print it

Answer (score 0):

But you are updating the status to "approved", so filtering on "application_submitted" gives nothing.

Comment: `
application_email = application_statuses.annotate(email=F('application__email')).values_list('email',flat=True)`


I was talking about this line. as you can see I have assigned the filtered values to application_email variable.
I was expecting `application_email` to be the same the whole time. but calling update replaced that. I actually need to know why this happened.
I have solved my problem using for loop